# Add Items from Array to HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

How I can iterate through an array in JavaScript while adding each element to an HTML table with a button? (i.e. click a button and "Rigatoni" gets added to a table.)

```js
function New_Item() {

  const Ingredients = ["Rigatoni", "Pesto", "Crushed Tomatoes", "Pasta Water", "Mozzarella Cheese", "Fresh Chopped Basil"]
  for (var x = 0; x < Ingredients.length; x++)
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = Ingredients;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <header>
    <tr>
      <td>Ingredient</td>
    </tr>
  </header>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="New_Item()">Add Ingredient</button>
```

Comment: Use brackets around everything that should occur in the `for` loop. Currently, only the first line under the `for` statement occurs in the loop. I suggest taking some basic JavaScript tutorials before going much farther.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide some sort of UI design

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you asked, this is my solution.

Edit: I added code with loop instead of button, you can remove button tag.

```html
<script>
var current=0;
const Ingredients = ["Rigatoni", "Pesto", "Crushed Tomatoes", "Pasta Water", "Mozzarella Cheese", "Fresh Chopped Basil"];
function New_Item() {
  if (current < Ingredients.length) {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(current+1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = Ingredients[current];
    current++;
  }
}

/* Second version with loop */

window.onload = function(e) {
  Ingredients.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
    New_Item_with_loop(index);
  });
}
function New_Item_with_loop(index) {
   var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
   var row = table.insertRow(index+1);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   cell1.innerHTML = Ingredients[index];
}
</script>
<table id="myTable">
  <header>
    <tr>
      <td>Ingredient</td>
    </tr>
  </header>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="New_Item()">Add Ingredient</button>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I need! Thank you. The only caveat I have is that I need to use this in a For or While loop. Can you amend it so it works that way?

Comment: I edit last comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below.

```
<table id="myTable">
<header>
    <tr>
    <td>Ingredient</td>
    </tr>
</header>
<tbody>
    
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="New_Item()">Add Ingredient</button>

<script>
const Ingredients = ["Rigatoni", "Pesto", "Crushed Tomatoes", "Pasta Water", "Mozzarella Cheese", "Fresh Chopped Basil"];

function New_Item() {
  var tableBody = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

  Ingredients.forEach(function(cellData) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    var cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
    row.appendChild(cell);

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });
}
</script>
```